# Magento 2: How to Implement Validation in UI-Component with parameters

Tags: arrays, magento2, uicomponents, validationrule

Ok. Everyone's got an answer on how to add validation rules to a ui-component field via XML. Unfortunately, I can't find anyone that seems to know how to implement a rule that requires a parameter or two. I'm sure the knowledge is out there, but nobody's asked the question. So here it is.

I'm looking to implement the `min-words` validation rule for a textarea. I've got something like this:

```xml
<field name="text_area">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            ...
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="min-words" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="length" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            ...
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

but I'm guessing, and this doesn't quite work. I'm close, but can't figure out what the "length" parameter is really supposed to be, and looking at the `rules.js` file doesn't provide any clues.

Answer (score 0):

So for the `min-words` rule, I found that it's simply:

```xml
<item name="min-words" xsi:type="number">10</item>
```

Having seen other implementations of parameters (not in validation rules), I thought I'd try this for the `range-words` rule, and discovered this format:

```xml
<item name="range-words" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="0" xsi:type="number">5</item>
   <item name="1" xsi:type="number">10</item>
</item>
```

This format would serve similar rules that require parameters, such as `zip-range, validate-number-range, validate-digits-range, validate-range, validate-date-range, validate-item-quantity, validate-file-type`. Being mindful to use the `name="0"` as array index for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J3ef.png)**You can find the list of all validation rules here.**

```
min_text_length
max_text_length
max-words
min-words
range-words
letters-with-basic-punc
alphanumeric
letters-only
no-whitespace
zip-range
integer
vinUS
dateITA
dateNL
time
time12h
phoneUS
phoneUK
mobileUK
stripped-min-length
email2
url2
credit-card-types
ipv4
ipv6
pattern
validate-no-html-tags
validate-select
validate-no-empty
validate-alphanum-with-spaces
validate-data
validate-street
validate-phoneStrict
validate-phoneLax
validate-fax
validate-email
validate-emailSender
validate-password
validate-admin-password
validate-url
validate-clean-url
validate-xml-identifier
validate-ssn
validate-zip-us
validate-date-au
validate-currency-dollar
validate-not-negative-number
validate-zero-or-greater
validate-greater-than-zero
validate-css-length
validate-number
validate-number-range
validate-digits
validate-digits-range
validate-range
validate-alpha
validate-code
validate-alphanum
validate-date
validate-identifier
validate-zip-international
validate-state
less-than-equals-to
greater-than-equals-to
validate-emails
validate-cc-number
validate-cc-ukss
required-entry
checked
not-negative-amount
validate-per-page-value-list
validate-new-password
validate-item-quantity
equalTo
```

For Example:

```
<field name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email Address</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">email</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">email</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="validate-email" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

**With minimum word range:**

```
<field name="address">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Address</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">address</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="min-words" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Comment: Please add a source for the full list of validation rules :)